# Difficulties scraping site using Poltergeist/PhantomJS/Capybara/Nokogiri. Getting held up on website

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have am trying to access a series of websites using poltergeist and copybara in a ruby script. I am having weird issues with a particular website: http://www.slate.com/

Here are the basic elements of the script:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
slate = "http://www.slate.com"
OPTIONS = {:js_errors => false, :debug => true, :timeout => 120, :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=false', '--load-images=false']}
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, OPTIONS)
end

session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)

session.driver.headers = {"User-Agent" => USER_AGENT}

session.visit slate
```

The response I get is odd and unlike other sites I am visiting in this way. upon `session.visit` it returns [object Object], then that the request was successful and gives me back my IRB prompt. But then I get automatically in my prompt `timeout timeout` in about 5 or 10 seconds and then `MySlateData data is empy`.

```
irb(main):016:0> session.visit slate
[object Object]
=> {"status"=>"success"}
irb(main):017:0> timeout timeout
MySlateData data is empty
```

Is there anyway to figure out why the response seems to keep hold of my session in a strange way? If I run `OPTIONS` with debug, I really don't see much more that's helpful.

```
irb(main):014:0> session.visit slate
{"id":"bba72e5e-fd27-4d92-bdb8-7cc0172afaf6","name":"visit","args":["http://www.slate.com"]}
[object Object]
{"command_id":"bba72e5e-fd27-4d92-bdb8-7cc0172afaf6","response":{"status":"success"}}
=> {"status"=>"success"}
irb(main):015:0> timeout timeout
MySlateData data is empty
```

For whatever reason, I'm not able to the scrape the resulting HTML because it's interfering with loading html into nokogiri.

Comment: What versions of poltergeist and PhantomJS  are you using?

Comment: Poltergeist is 1.8.1 and PhantomJS is 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara isn't keeping hold of your session.  Poltergeist/PhantomJS is running the "browser" asynchronously from your code - The extraneous content you're seeing appear in your output is the output of console logs from the website you've visited.  Making sure you're using the latest versions of poltergeist (1.9+) and phantomjs (2.1.1+) may remove some of them since they will create less errors in the page

Comment: Hmm that makes sense but it seems, for whatever reason, that these errors might be interfering with attempts to scrape information from the page using nokogiri. Though perhaps that's a separate question. Upgrading now.

Comment: Any errors would definitely cause issues with attempts to scrape info, since an error would generally indicate something hasn't actually loaded correctly.